# How to write javascript block in jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, pug

I need to write some javascript code in my jade template but don't wrap inside script tag:

```
body
   container
       p
          - var obj = {
          -    "price": 100,
          -    "qty: 3
          -};

          - var result = obj.price * obj.qty;

          Result is: !{result}.
```

In the code above I do some computations and output result. All works fine but looks ugly due multiple `-`. Does jade support some blocks to write javascript without using of multiple `-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jade doesn't currently support stringing multiple lines of [unbuffered code](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/) together. Each `-` should be followed by a complete statement.

The `obj` will have to be initialized in one:

```
p
    - var obj = { price: 100, qty: 3 };
```

Or set in multiple statements:

```
p
    - var obj = {};
    - obj.price = 100;
    - obj.qty = 3;
```

Or, defined as "locals" to render with:

```
var jade = require('jade');

var html = jade.renderFile(__dirname + '/template.jade', {
    obj: {
        price: 100,
        qty: 3
    }
});
```

```
p Result is: #{obj.price * obj.qty).
```

---

Also note that the `Result ...` will need a `|` prefix to signify it as a [line of text](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/) when it's on its own line.

```
p
    | Result is #{result}
```

Comment: Thanks for the full answer. Do you know about plans on adding this feature in jade?